# Is there a financial benefit for buyers from using community currencies?

Tags: currency, economics

My city is introducing its own local currency, so I've been reading about similar established projects like the [Brixton Pound](http://brixtonpound.org/). I understand that local businesses will benefit from it thanks to the [local multiplier effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_multiplier_effect), but what about me personally? Should I expect any personal benefits from using it (e.g. more advantageous prices), or am I supposed to use it by a voluntary choice without any financial incentive?

Comment: I imagine that depends on the program, doesn't it?  But I can't imagine why anyone would be willing to use it unless it had some advantage (such as better prices or at least some sort of points/rewards program).

Comment: @Joe I don't know. Fair trade incentive for example doesn't offer anything to the consumer: you simply chose to support farmers from developing countries by buying their products.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: NO, there is **no financial benefits** for you to expect in a local currency even if some might give tiny discounts on local sales.

Local currencies are attractive for small business or communities, they are perfectly legal and starting to be popular in a lot of places. Local currencies encourage individuals and businesses to *exchange goods and services locally*.

Using them is **like investing in your community**. It could give you the feeling of doing something good for your community. Check [this article](http://www.centerforneweconomics.org/content/local-currencies) for a discussion on the subject.

They should **not** be considered **investments**. Local currencies do not offer the same financial security and some could be like monopoly money, but that would be another subject or question to debate.

So, to summarize: no money to be made for your personal use, but some real social and financial benefits for your community. Would'nt that be **a kind of personal benefit** for you ?